# Angular 10 Jasmine component not updating properties after function is called

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm calling a function that sets an int value to 0 in my unit test.

Here's the code for the UT

```
it('should clear filters', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'clearFilters');
    const button: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.mdi-filter-variant-remove');
    button.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    expect(component.clearFilters).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.filtersCount).toBe(0);
    expect(component.clearFiltersEvent.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

Here is some of the code of the function:

```
clearFilters(): void {
   this.filtersCount = 0;
```

I can't figure out why expect(component.filtersCount).toBe(0); fails. it's set to another number diferent than 0. The other expects are working. The function is being called.
It's my understanding that due to the function being called, the property should be 0.

What am I missing?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `spyOn` a method, we lose implementation details of the method (basically it returns undefined even though it gets called).

To get what you want, try:

```
it('should clear filters', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(component, 'clearFilters').and.callThrough(); // add and.callThrough() so you don't lose implementation details
    const button: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('.mdi-filter-variant-remove');
    button.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    expect(component.clearFilters).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.filtersCount).toBe(0);
    expect(component.clearFiltersEvent.emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```